# Using reCAPTCHA on https://name.github.io

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

Is possible to use reCAPTCHA on https://name.github.io? I set as domain https://name.github.io on reCAPTCHA site, put the site key in  Tag, actually I use react-recaptcha package, but is't now functioning, I receive message: ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key. I am using reCAPTCHA type:v2 Checkbox. Has anyone idea?

Answer (score 0):

From the [reCAPTCHA FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#recently-my-recaptcha-widget-started-displaying-invalid-site-key-whats-happening):

> **Recently my reCAPTCHA widget started displaying "Invalid site key". What's happening?**
>   If you are seeing this error, your reCAPTCHA site key is no longer
>   valid. To activate, please register a new key and follow the
>   instructions on that page.